# How to fix a Index+Match based on input value thats also dynamic

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect, excel-match

I have a great challenge I hope you can help me with. 
**What I want to achieve:**

- In the sheetname “Overal campaign information” I have an identical setup to the other sheetnames (for example Week 1 – Email, Week 1 – CPC and so on).
- I want to user to first select their week and year and based (under E1)  on these to selections, you can select a type that matches that week and year input.

**What have I tried?**

- I have written an INDEX+MATCH that works well, but that is based on a hard coded sheet name and is not dynamic.
- I have also tried the INDIRECT function to find information regardless of worksheet name, but failed hard
- I have  tried to CONCATENATE year+week to get a key to match against point 1, but also not succeeded

**Wanted result**

- Based on the time frame selection (week and year) the type will show available types that matches that input.
- Then it will fill in the information in C1:C13 and B17:V:300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really clear what you means by "fill in the information in C1:C13". But formula in `'Overal campaign information'!B17` could be

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("'Week "&$F$2&" - " & $F$4&"'!$B$17"),ROW(B17)-17,COLUMN(B17)-2)
```

This then can be filled into `'Overal campaign information'!B17:V300`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved one part of the issue. 

Whats left:
- In the dropdown menu in 'Overal campaign information'!F4, I want this to dynamic update it content based on what year and week you select (so you only show types that is valid)

Comment: @Dendera: Sorry but this is not how stackoverflow works. It works: One problem - one question - answers for solving that one problem. It works not: telling a whole project requirement and expecting the whole project solution then.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. Thanks for your help anyway, solved one great issue :-)